# get first and last name from e-mail address in Enterprise G-Suite

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to find a user's name from their e-mail address. I thought I could use `People.People.get` as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/people#get_the_person_for_a_google_account) but that requires knowing the user's account ID.

How can I get information about the user if I only know their e-mail?

And I don't think I can use the Directory API cause I don't have admin access.

Comment: is [`ContactsApp.getContact()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getContact(String)) viable for your situation? If not, when you say "from their email address", you mean from the contact information available e.g. when adding a user to your contacts in gmail?

Comment: So in our setup, I/we don't add contacts to our ContactsApp. If I go to https://contacts.google.com/ I won't see anything under Contacts. Instead we have a Directory and everything is in their. So I need to somehow search against that. From what I can tell, ContactsApp does not search the entire Directory.

Comment: Then perhaps use [Apps Script Admin SDK Directory service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) and then [use that API to search for the user's email](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users)? Edit: Actually, [it shows how to search for the email right here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#get_user), just `AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Admin Directory API to get user's details. While making the URL call, you need to specify a parameter in the request body which is (viewType:"domain_public"), so you will get the basic details of the user in your domain without having admin rights.

Reference Link : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without Admin Rights, on the link you mentioned you need the AccountId which can only be retrieved by having Admin Rights and Access to the Directory API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) which you mentioned tyou don't have access to.

You could ask to your Administrator to get an Admin Role https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176?hl=en to use the Admin SDK for complete your task, it will be easier for you. The other way I don't know how the contact sharing is setup in your organization because you should be able to check the information of the contact when sending an email or adding it to your contact list.

I hope this information can be of help. Greetings.